# How to decode stringified unicode?

Tags: java, json, unicode

I'm passing a stringfied string to Java using Ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    data: {
       item: JSON.stringify( object with unicode string values ) 
    }
});
```

I used to parse that in PHP with `urldecode` and all the characters decoded very well. Now, I need to do that in Java. I tried `URLDecoder.decode(string, "UTF-8")`, but it didn't work.  What should I use instead?

**Updated**: by "didn't work", I mean I get the following result:

title:"æä¼æ æ¿ä»  (from JAVA)

Instead of title:"最优惠房  (from PHP)

**Updated 2** :

It looks like I have to use the following before `request.getParameter`:

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")
```

And my Ajax request must be of POST type.

Comment: did you try using a JSON parser?

Comment: @jtahlborn // looking into it right now.

Comment: @jtahlborn // see my comment for dacwe's post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use some existing library that will do it automatically? Check out:

- [JSON in Java](http://www.json.org/java/)
- [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: Well the thing is, I'm not trying to convert the string into java object. I'm saving the string into session then simply output the string later. So..I'm not sure if I can use JSON parser

Comment: Sure you can use a parser! Use the object-structure as a way to easily extract the string, like an intermediate pass...

Comment: Ha! haven't thought about that! I guess I can decode into object then use toString again.

Comment: well...tried to parse the string into object. I'm having the same problem.

Comment: $request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")  worked for me..thanks though!